# MySQL Workbench Forward Engineer onto two databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have two MySQL databases:

- **`Production`**
- **`Dev`**

Both of them have the same schema

Every time I make a change on the `dev` database using the forward engineer tool on MySQL workbench I have to extract the SQL script and manually replace all instances of the `dev` database with the production ones.

Then I run the script on the production database.

Is it possible when I change something on the `dev` database to reflect the new changes automatically on the production one ?

Comment: Yes, this is called: replication and a completely different setup. MySQL Workbench does not automatically propagate changes to any target server and only can work with a single server at a time.

Comment: The problem with replication is that it happens automatically whereas I want to replicate the db only if I wish to do so. Any way I can set up the replication in order to achieve this?